# Updating code from lexical-let to lexical-binding: t

Tags: elisp, lexical-binding

[This](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Function_composition#Emacs_Lisp) code shows an elisp function (third example) using `lexical-let`, which is now passe as I understand. How would it be written today with lexical scope now being a quasi-built-in feature of elisp? My first guess is just to drop the `lexical-` prefix to `let`, but does that change the rest of code, especially the `funcall` uses? Also, what are we winning with the lexical scope version over the first example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> [This](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Function_composition#Emacs_Lisp) code shows an elisp function (third example) using `lexical-let`

This is the (renamed) third example in the linked page:

```el
(eval-when-compile (require 'cl)) ;; for `lexical-let' macro
(defun compose-cl (f g)
  (lexical-let ((f f)
                (g g))
    (lambda (x)
      (funcall f (funcall g x)))))
```

> which is now passe as I understand.

Yes.

> How would it be written today with lexical scope now being a quasi-built-in feature of elisp?

It is entirely built-in, just not enabled by default everywhere. Emacs 27 enables it in a few more places by default, such as `*scratch*`, `*ielm*`, etc.

> My first guess is just to drop the `lexical-` prefix to `let`

With `lexical-binding`, there is no need for `lexical-let` or `let` at all, as the local variables `f` and `g` are automatically captured by the contained closure:

```el
(defun compose-lex (f g)
  (lambda (x)
    (funcall f (funcall g x))))
```

> but does that change the rest of code, especially the `funcall` uses?

No; see below.

> Also, what are we winning with the lexical scope version over the first example?

This is the (renamed) first example in the linked page:

```el
(defun compose-quoted (f g)
  `(lambda (x) (,f (,g x))))
```

This works regardless of `lexical-binding`, but has the disadvantage of being opaque to the interpreter/byte-compiler, which sees only a (back)quoted list, not a function. As Stefan mentions [in a comment](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/50471/updating-code-from-lexical-let-to-lexical-binding-t/50474?noredirect=1#comment77758_50474), you miss out on several important features as a result of this, including evaluation speed and compiler warnings (the byte-compiler can't optimise or analyse quoted lambdas), debugging backtraces, the ability to step through the function with Edebug, etc. Quoting lambdas is therefore frowned upon, and is usually avoidable.

> but does that change the rest of code, especially the `funcall` uses?

Let's see.  Compare the (abridged) function slots of the three aforementioned definitions:

```el
(symbol-function #'compose-quoted)
(lambda (f g)
  (list 'lambda '(x)
        (list f (cons g '(x)))))

(symbol-function #'compose-cl)
(lambda (f g)
  (let ((cl-f f)
        (cl-g g))
    (list 'lambda '(&rest cl-rest)
          (list 'apply
                (lambda (g0 f0 x)
                  (funcall (symbol-value f0)
                           (funcall (symbol-value g0) x)))
                (list 'quote cl-g)
                (list 'quote cl-f)
                'cl-rest))))

(symbol-function #'compose-lex)
(closure (t)
         (f g)
  (lambda (x)
    (funcall f (funcall g x))))
```

and the (abridged) values they return:

```el
(compose-quoted #'1+ #'1-)
'(lambda (x) (1+ (1- x)))

(compose-cl #'1+ #'1-)
'(lambda (&rest cl-rest)
   (apply (lambda (g0 f0 x)
            (funcall (symbol-value f0)
                     (funcall (symbol-value g0) x)))
          'cl-g 'cl-f cl-rest))

(compose-lex #'1+ #'1-)
(closure ((g . 1-)
          (f . 1+)
          t)
         (x)
  (funcall f (funcall g x)))
```

Comment: I think the printed representation of the different functions doesn't matter that much.  Some of the more important differences would be speed, compiler-warnings, interaction with Edebug and with the backtrace-debugger.

Comment: @Stefan I only listed the printed representations for demonstrative purposes, as the OP seemed concerned about `lexical-binding` changing the code somehow. I'll include your examples under the benefits of evaluating lambdas, thanks.